# HTTP 400 to specific client request

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, https

I have a spring boot application and this receives and responses message back to the request from SoapUI or IE but not from third party vendor application. I don't see any logs on this spring boot application's embedded tomcat for the request from the third party vendor application. As I cannot change the logs/code of this third party vendor application, it is hard to trace.

below is the code where I define this controller

```
@PostMapping("/Message")
    public ResponseEntity Message(@RequestBody String body, HttpMethod method,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws URISyntaxException {

        log.info("Message method of MessageController invoked");
```

What would be the possible cause of the issue?

Regards,

Comment: You could start your app with more debugging info -Dlogging.level.org.apache=debug  / -Ddebug=true should dump the requests. And then analyze, what is different with that failing request compared to the sopaui request

Comment: According to my experience, the cause of HTTP return code **400** for **Post** API is often missing request body! So, maybe you can check the third party vendor application if sent the request with body first.

Comment: [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-9] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1b849ba:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@65f6f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/123.456.78.90:8444 remote=/123.456.78.90:57559]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]

Comment: java.lang.Exception: null
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doClose(NioEndpoint.java:1165) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.close(SocketWrapperBase.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.cancelledKey(NioEndpoint.java:667) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22]

Comment: Above is error message after I added more logs. Maybe something goes wrong when the request comes from the same host????  FYI. this spring boot application receives the request from third party vendor application in same host and send the request to other web service in other host. all communication is over HTTPS.